# How to extract multiple citations separated by tags from a text using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, citations

I have a manually an input file consisting of citations, each in the format:

> < S sid ="2" ssid = "2">It differs from previous machine
>   learning-based NERs in that it uses information from the whole
>   document to classify each word, with just one classifier.< /S>< S sid
>   ="3" ssid = "3">Previous work that involves the gathering of information from the whole document often uses a secondary classifier,
>   which corrects the mistakes of a primary sentence- based classifier.<
>   /S>

Here is my current approach using python's re module:

```
citance = citance[citance.find(">")+1:citance.rfind("<")]
fd.write(citance+"\n")
```

I am trying to extract everything from the occurrence of first closing angular bracket(">") to the last opening angular bracket("<"). However, in case of multiple citances, this approach fails as the middle tags too get extracted in the output:

> It differs from previous machine learning-based NERs in that it uses
>   information from the whole document to classify each word, with just
>   one classifier.< /S>< S sid ="3" ssid = "3">Previous work that involves
>   the gathering of information from the whole document often uses a
>   secondary classifier, which corrects the mistakes of a primary
>   sentence- based classifier.

My desired output:

> It differs from previous machine learning-based NERs in that it uses
>   information from the whole document to classify each word, with just
>   one classifier. Previous work that involves
>   the gathering of information from the whole document often uses a
>   secondary classifier, which corrects the mistakes of a primary
>   sentence- based classifier.

How can I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with python regex module : `re`
by doing :

```
re.findall(r'\">(.*?)<', text_to_parse)
```

This method will return from one to multiple quotes, but after you can just join them if you want a unified text (`" ".join(....)`)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using re module, have a look to [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

This is a XML/HTML parser, thus you can get everything between tags.

For you, it'll be something like :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_text = '< S sid ="2" ssid = "2">It differs from previous machine learning-based NERs in that it uses information from the whole document to classify each word, with just one classifier.< /S>< S sid ="3" ssid = "3">Previous work that involves the gathering of information from the whole document often uses a secondary classifier, which corrects the mistakes of a primary sentence- based classifier.< /S>'

text_soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, 'lxml')

output = text_soup.find_all('S', attrs = {'sid': '2'})
```

output will contains text:

> It differs from previous machine learning-based NERs in that it uses information from the whole document to classify each word, with just one classifier.

Moreover, if you just want to remove html tags :

```
import re

xml_text = '< S sid ="2" ssid = "2">It differs from previous machine learning-based NERs in that it uses information from the whole document to classify each word, with just one classifier.< /S>< S sid ="3" ssid = "3">Previous work that involves the gathering of information from the whole document often uses a secondary classifier, which corrects the mistakes of a primary sentence- based classifier.< /S>'

re.sub('<.*?>', '', html_text)
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import re

string = ">here is some text<>here is some more text<"
matches = re.findall(">(.*?)<", string)
for match in matches: print match
```

It seems like you are having a problem getting too many results. The match for "here is some more text<" could be from the first to last character in the string because they are ">" and "<" while ignoring the ones in the middle. the '.*?' idiom will make it find the maximum number of hits.